# (Sparx) Shared SQL Server Repository Causing DB Lockouts

Tags: sql-server, enterprise-architect

For our shared repository, there are regularly scheduled password updates of the database to comply with security policies. Whenever we update, there are database lockouts that occur due to some users still attempting to connect with the old password.

Is there a better way to use the repository in a shared collaborative environment?

Comment: Why is it that I have to laugh when seeing people enforcing a password change regularly that finally ends up in post-its near the monitor?

Comment: I'm not an admin, but doesn't Windoze allow to sign up a DB based on a central LDAP (or whatever Mickeysoft is calling it)?

Comment: It depends on your company policy. I'd recommend to let LDAP (or IIRC it's Active Directory in Windoze) do the authorization stuff and not use DB login.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup SQL server to accepts windows authentication instead of using an SQL server user and password.

Using windows authentication you get:

- Setup security using AD groups. Anyone in the group automatically gets access to the database, anyone not in the group doesn't have access anymore.
- No more failed attempts anymore
- No more need to change the db password anymore
- You can track the actual users connected to the database instead of having all users connect using the shared SQL server credentials.

Comment: You are already giving them that through the SQL server user. What is the worst that can happen? That they would destroy the model? They can do that now as well, except that you can't track who did it, and that you can't control access to the database. Anyone with access to the shortcut file has full access to the database.

Comment: EA users and SQL Server users are independent (although both can use windows authentication). With version 14.1 you can setup EA to user AD groups as well so you don't need to import all of the users manually.

Comment: Did you import the other users from AD as EA users?